# Finding induced subgraphs that are also trees

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, algorithm

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, I need to find a subgraph consisting of $m$ vertices $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$, and the [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of this subgraph should also be a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

For example, suppose $G$ is a $3\times3$ grid graph, and the subgraph should include vertices $\{6,8,1\}$. Shown below is an example of a subgraph (edges in green) which includes these vertices.

[image]

However, its induced subgraph is

[image]

which is not a tree.

A solution for this specific example would be;

[image]

and its induced subgraph,

[image]

which is a tree.

Comment: why is it that the subgraph formed by green edges in the second picture _not_ a tree?

Comment: the subgraph is a tree, however the induced subgraph, which includes all the edges between the vertices in the original graph, is not.

Comment: According to the definition in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph), the only _induced subgraph_  formed  by vertices $\{6,8,1\}$ in your example is the graph with vertex list  $\{6,8,1\}$ and no edges.

Comment: Ah ok, i understand the confusion..i should've been more clear. The induced subgraph is formed from all the vertices in the subgraph, not just $\{6,8,1\}$.

Comment: thank you Dotman.

Comment: so other solutions include `{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 8}` and `{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 6, 6 <-> 9, 8 <-> 9}`?

Comment: @kglr yes you are correct

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

A less-brute force modification:

```
ClearAll[findInducedSubtree]
findInducedSubtree[g_, vlst_] /; {} === FindCycle[Subgraph[g, vlst], ∞, 1] := 
 Module[{k = 1, res = {}}, 
   While[{} === (res = Flatten @ 
    Map[If[TreeGraphQ @ #, #, {}] & @ Subgraph[g, Join[vlst, #]] &]@
    Subsets[Complement[VertexList@g, vlst], {k++}])]; 
   MinimalBy[VertexCount] @ res]
```

***Examples:***

```
vlst = {6, 8, 1};

gg = GridGraph[{3, 3}, 
   PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge", VertexLabels -> Automatic,
   VertexSize -> (Alternatives @@ vlst -> Medium)];

Row[HighlightGraph[gg, #, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  findInducedSubtree[gg, vlst]]
```

[image]

```
vls = {21, 2, 3, 7, 35, 11, 32, 26, 30, 16, 8, 25};

gg6 = GridGraph[{6, 6}, PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge", 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   VertexSize -> (Alternatives @@ vls -> Medium)];

HighlightGraph[gg6, Subgraph[gg6, vls], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
pics = HighlightGraph[gg6, #, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
  findInducedSubtree[gg6, vls];


Multicolumn[pics, 4]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];

rg = RandomGraph[{30, 50}, PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge", 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
   EdgeStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
   VertexSize -> (Alternatives @@ vls -> Large)];
```

A vertex list that does not induce a subgraph with cycles:

```
While[{} =!= FindCycle[
    Subgraph[rg, vls = RandomSample[Range@30, 12]], ∞, 1]];
vls
```

> ```
> {3, 10, 14, 27, 17, 28, 18, 8, 9, 23, 4, 20}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[rg, Subgraph[rg, vls], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
trees = findInducedSubtree[rg, vls];

Row[HighlightGraph[rg, #, ImageSize -> 600] & /@ trees]
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

A brute-force approach:

```
ClearAll[selectSubgraphs]

selectSubgraphs[g_, vlst_] := Select[TreeGraphQ] @ 
   Map[Subgraph[g, #] &] @
   Select[ContainsAll @ vlst] @ 
   Subsets[VertexList @ g, {Length @ vlst, VertexCount @ g}]
```

***Examples:***

```
vlst = {6, 8, 1};

gg = GridGraph[{3, 3}, 
   PlotTheme -> "ThickEdge", VertexLabels -> Automatic,
   VertexSize -> (Alternatives @@ vlst -> Medium)];

Multicolumn[HighlightGraph[gg,  #] & /@ selectSubgraphs[gg, vlst], 4]
```

[image]

If desired, select the subgraphs with minimum number of vertices:

```
Row[HighlightGraph[gg, #, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  MinimalBy[VertexCount]@selectSubgraphs[gg, vlst]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, thank you. However its not really applicable in cases beyond $5\times5$. Im looking to analyse this problem upto $10\times10$ case. Hence I'm not marking this as the answer (yet).

Comment: is your base graph always a grid graph ?

Comment: Not necessarily…. However It would  be nice to have a solution that at least works on grid graphs

Comment: Dotman, please see the update.

Comment: An idea that I have now l after seeing the results of your code is that the solution tree is composed of some of the shortest paths between the m vertices . searching just within 'the subgraphs formed by the shortest paths might work faster , however I don't have a proof for whether this will work or not. Maybe a variation of kruskals algorithm where shortest paths are iteatively added to form the tree might work.

Comment: your second example is wrong. 6,16 and 17,27 are neighbours, hence the induced subgraph is not a tree